# proper method to get selected record from extjs grid

Tags: extjs

I need to get selected record from extjs grid but get

```
Uncaught TypeError: grid.getSelectionModel is not a function
```

got this view

```
Ext.define( 'App.view.Measuries', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.measuries',
title: 'Мероприятия',

autoShow: false,
modal: true,
resizable: true,

initComponent: function()
{
    this.items = [
            {
        
            xtype: 'grid',
            alias: 'measuries_grid',
            bodyPadding: 8,
            defaults: { width: 1000, labelAlign: 'top' },
            
            columns:[
                { header: 'п/п',             width: 60, dataIndex: 'm_number',     menuDisabled: true, sortable: false},
                { header: 'Мероприятие',             width: 340, dataIndex: 'm_text',     menuDisabled: true, sortable: false},
                { header: 'Плановая дата выполнения', width: 146, dataIndex: 'date_plan', menuDisabled: true, sortable: false, xtype: 'datecolumn', format:'d.m.Y', align: 'center'},
                { header: 'Фактическая дата выполнения', width: 146, dataIndex: 'date_done', menuDisabled: true, sortable: false, xtype: 'datecolumn', format:'d.m.Y', align: 'center'},
                { header: 'Выполнено', width: 95, dataIndex: 'isdone', menuDisabled: true, sortable: false, align: 'center',
                                                                                                                renderer: function ( v )
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    return '<img src="img/' + v.toString().toLowerCase() + '.png">';
                                                                                                                }},
                { header: 'Отказ',             width: 95, dataIndex: 'faultid',     menuDisabled: true, sortable: false}, 
                    ],
                
            store : 'Measuries'
            
            }   
        ];
```

and this controller (well a part of it)

```
editMeasuries: function()
{
    var grid = this.getMeasuries();
    console.log(grid);
    var rec  = grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected();
    /*var sel = grid.getSelectionModel();
    var rec = sel.getLastSelected();*/
    if ( rec )
    {
        var view = Ext.widget( 'measuries-edit' );
        view.down( 'form' ).loadRecord( rec );
    }
},
```

it seems trouble with "this.getMeasuries()" part. My "alias : 'widget.measuries'" go to 'Ext.window.Window' and getSelecionModel() requires a grid. I've tried to set alias to grid item inside 'Ext.window.Window' but got error too.
How i can change my controller part to get things right?
Sorry for possible mistakes, my english is weak so as extjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an `itemId` for the grid and use `getComponent` on your window to get your grid:

```
this.items = [
    {
        itemId: 'myGrid', // add this line
        xtype: 'grid',
...
```

Then in your 'editMeasures` function do like this:

```
editMeasuries: function()
{
    var myWindow = this.getMeasuries();
    var myGrid = myWindow.getComponent('myGrid');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `itemId` you might want to use `references`, which is the faster way of handling items in the viewController.

(I am taking the code from @Peter Koltai)

```
this.items = [{
    reference: 'myGrid', // add this line
    xtype:     'grid',
    ...
```

Then in your 'editMeasures` function do like this (you do not need myWindow, it's just there to demonstrate a different approach):

```
editMeasuries: function()
{
    let myWindow = this.getView(),
        myGrid   = this.lookup('myGrid');
    ...
```